# What debug levels are available for telnetlib?

Tags: python-2.7, telnetlib

What do the debug level numbers correspond to in python's `telnetlib`?  What is the maximum debug level?  I've set numbers up to 400 without causing an exception.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.set_debuglevel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [currently implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/telnetlib.py#L247), the only meaningful debug levels are `0` and `> 0`.

Basically, you can set `debuglevel` as high as Python's `long` datatype allows you to. However, it will not change debugging output past the initial `1`.